# Name the Chat Room

Tags: discussion, chat

The Puzzling Chat room, give it a name! [(and come in there and hash it out!)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/puzzling)

Edit: This should have been done at the start .... a deadline for this 'process'.

I propose: 1 week from today (Friday 23 May 2014 @ 00:00:01UTC ( Thurs 22 May @ 20:00:01EST, etc)), highest voted answer determines chat room name. The suggestion with the highest aggregate votes wins.

Answer (score 10):

It should be something...puzzling, like *The Green Llama*.

> Bob: Why is the chat room named "The Green Llama"?
>
> Jim: Do you find that puzzling?
>
> Bob: Well, yeah.
>
> Jim: There you go.

Comment: This is an AWFUL idea.  But it made me laugh so hard I'm up voting it anyway. :)

Comment: @Jaydles I think you misspelled "Awesome" :-)

Answer (score 6):

We could follow the lead of the site's icon and just go with

### ?????

(But then again not everyone shares my admittedly odd sense of humor.)

Comment: It should be an interrobang (‽), if anything. A place where ?(Q) and !(A) meet.

Comment: Or c?a? r??m. Or changing the hangman letters every day/few days.

Answer (score 6):

## Thebes

(The city whose entrance was guarded by the riddling Sphinx.)

Comment: I actually really like this one. Maybe "The Gates of Thebes"?

Answer (score 5):

### Outside the Box

^^^^ My suggestion

Comment: Not too hot on this, but I don't really have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolf, Goat, and Cabbage Boat

A reference to a popular [river crossing puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_crossing_puzzle), and it rhymes!

Comment: I like the rhyming, but it seems a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

## [The Locked Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locked_room_mystery)

Comment: Sounds like a name for the moderator room.

Answer (score 0):

## Off the Grid

(Inspired by @rolfl's answer)

Comment: Sounds like it should be the chat room for [sustainability.se].

Answer (score -4):

**ƃuᴉlzznԀ**

Upside down AND Backwards

Comment: Bad for screenreaders.