# Make [??.SE] a shortcut for Puzzling

Tags: feature-request

Every SE site has a special syntax for comments and chat which auto-links to the site. Puzzling's is

> [puzzling.SE]

I propose we also add

> [??.SE]

It's a lot shorter, it's fun, and I predict that the ?? in the icon are going to become part of the site's identity (and hey, [at least one person agrees with me!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/name-the-chat-room?6#6)).

Comment: How about `?!` instead of `??` ? I mean, we aren't just about puzzling, but answering the puzzles too!?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I said ?? because that appears in the icon on the little SE bubble thing :)

Comment: I know! I personally like the `?!` hence. :)

Comment: I still haven't even seen the logo or style as I'm not back to an actual computer yet today

Comment: Eh, personally I'd go with "puz.se".

Answer (score 2):

Though this would be a nice easter egg, I don't really see it catching on or being practical. The trilogy get their two-letter abbreviations because they are much larger and well known, and more likely to be referred to in comments. If we get this, the only people who will know it is maybe a dozen of us who see this post.

Comment: I think `?` is a special escape for passing data to servers in a web url. I'm not sure this would make a difference, but still...

Comment: Yes, it is used to separate arguments in a GET request (in the URL). That said, I'm quite sure that is not a technological hurdle to implementing this.

Comment: Having just discovered the "insert coin" chat easter egg a few weeks ago, I think I'm probably influenced in the direction of wanting neat things like this :) I was thinking that if we used the shortcut in comments on the main site often, it would be noticed by users who haven't seen the post and then they would know about it. But you're completely right that it's just an easter egg and not at all necessary. I just think it'd be fun :)